# How to check if the text inserted in editText exist in SQLite database then return a message if it exist and if not return different message

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

i'm new to programming, i'm trying make an app that creates an SQLite database, adds a table to said database, allows me to update the table and view the data inserted into it. then, i want it to check if the text (for example a name) i insert into editText  exists in the database and return a message, let's say "employee exist" if the text is found and a different message "employee not found" if the name is not in the database.

i have managed to do everything except for the part where the app is supposed to check if the name exist in the db and returns the message. this is as far as i have gotten:

DatabaseHelper looks like this:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int dbVersion = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="numere_masini.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="tabel_masini";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="NUME";
    public static final String COL_3="PRENUME";
    public static final String COL_4="NUMAR_DOSAR";
    public static final String COL_5="COD_ORGANIGRAMA";
    public static final String COL_6="CENTRU_COST";
    public static final String COL_7="NUMAR_AUTO_1";
    public static final String COL_8="NUMAR_AUTO_2";
    public static final String COL_9="NUMAR_AUTO_3";
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String createTable = "Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COL_1 + " Integer Primary Key AutoIncrement," +
            COL_2 + " Text," +
            COL_3 + " Text," +
            COL_4 + " Text," +
            COL_5 + " Text," +
            COL_6 + " Text," +
            COL_7 + " Text," +
            COL_8 + " Text," +
            COL_9 + " Text" + ");";


    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,dbVersion );

    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDatabase) {
        this.db= SQLiteDatabase;
        db.execSQL(createTable);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);

    }


    public boolean cautaNumar(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL_2}, COL_2+"=?", new String[] {}, null, null, null, "1");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return true; // a row was found
        }
        return false; // no row was found

    }
```

MainActivity is this

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editNume, editPrenume, editNumar_dosar,  editCod_organigrama, editCentru_cost, editNumar_auto_1, editNumar_auto2, editNumar_auto3,editTextId, editCauta;
    Button btnAdaugaNumar;
    Button btnverificaNumar;
    Button btnActualizeazaInformatii;
    Button btnAfiseazaDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        editNume= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_nume);
        editPrenume= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_prenume);
        editNumar_dosar= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_numar_dosar);
        editCod_organigrama= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_cod_organigrama);
        editCentru_cost= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_centru_cost);
        editNumar_auto_1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_numar_auto_1);
        editNumar_auto2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_numar_auto_2);
        editNumar_auto3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_numar_auto_3);
        editTextId=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_id) ;
        editCauta=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_cauta);

        btnAdaugaNumar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_adauga_angajat);
        btnverificaNumar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_verifica_numar);
        btnActualizeazaInformatii=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_actualizeaza_informatii);
        btnAfiseazaDb=(Button) findViewById((R.id.button_afiseaza_db));
        AddData();
        viewAll();
        UpdateData();
        verificaNumar();
    }

    // i have no idea how ro write this segment
     public void verificaNumar (){

        String cautare= editCauta.getText().toString();
        if(myDb.cautaNumar()) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "employee exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"employee not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: yes, you have to query DB. what are you findings when you run the code where exactly you are stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Class DatabaseHelper:

```
public boolean cautaNumar(String name){
        boolean flag = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL_2}, COL_2+"=?", new String[] {}, null, null, null, "1");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if(cursor.getString("name").equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                flag = true;
            }
            else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

In Class MainActivity:

```
public void verificaNumar (){
            String cautare = editCauta.getText().toString();
            if(myDb.cautaNumar(cautare)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "employee exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"employee not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have tried the code but it gives the error: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Comment: update: I went back to the original code in  class DatabaseHelper and only updated the MainActivity class, it worked this way. :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below code:**

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SqliteDatabase sqlite = db.getReadableDatabase();

EditText edit = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
String edit_string = edit.getText().toString();

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TO_MATCH + "=?", new String[] {edit_string}, null, null, null);

if ( cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 

else {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text doesnt matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```